# MySite Owner Managed Metadata Service

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, my-site, managed-metadata-service

I have two MMS Fields (created on rootweb, added to myContentType which in turn added to MyDocumentLibrary) which works fine everywhere in the farm, but they do not work correctly on MySite.
this is the scenario.
The owner of Site collection of MySite has been changed to domain\Administrator. so the user "test" is not owner of the site collection (http://blah/personal/test). but he belongs to a grupp which has some permission levels.
When test user tries to go to "Edit properties" of a document within the library it gets 403 (forbidden) error.

1. if I add Full controll to the grupp test user belongs to, still he get same error
2. if I change the site.Owner to "test" he does not get any error and he can change properties and MMS Fields for documents. but the user is not allowed to be owner.

How do I solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 1):

that is an interesting one.. ALthough i don't have an answer on your solution, please keep in mind that your strategy of removing site collection admin permissions from the mySite "owner" will be reverted by some timerjob!